# Build jung for eclipse

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a project for eclipse using maven.
The project is jung.(http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
According to their documentation,i need to

1.download the archive with the .jar files

2.extract it to a folder

3.Cd to the folder and run mvn eclipse:eclipse

If i understand everything correctly,after that it should create a project for eclipse and i can link to the project via the varialbe M2_REPO in my own project and use the libraries in my code.

But,the problem is that the maven says [INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1.
(or [INFO] Cannot execute mojo: eclipse. It requires a project with an existing pomxml, but the build is not using one.for maven 2)
I don't thing it is logically correct,because it requires the project itself before creating the project.

After some googling i figured out that i need some project with a pom.xml file.
Moreover,i can create such project using maven by typing
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

Ok,it creates the project,but what is next? How to bind the jung libraries to the project?

I had made some tries (like moving the jars and the xml file to each other,an executing the maven commands,but i have got no good results).

So,can somebody clearly describe the steps i should follow after getting the error "NO POM.XML" file?
My final goal is  an eclipse project that uses jung libraries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are downloading the pre-built version, intended for people who just want to make use of the library. Hence it doesn't have a pom.xml file which is required for Maven to build the project, and may not even have the source code.

If you want to build it yourself, then follow the instructions at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual#Appendix:HowtoBuildJUNG remembering to use the second option given to check the code out of CVS ("If you are a user, do this:"). Or you could check it out of CVS from within Eclipse, in which case you wouldn't need to do the 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' part. If you are using Eclipse with a Maven project, then I would recommend installing the M2E plugin for Eclipse, available from the Eclipse marketplace. You can then enable the project as a Maven project and it makes it much easier to work with.

I've just built it myself according to the instructions (although not set it up in Eclipse) and they worked fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everthing is clear for me after your post:) I just need  to use the libraries ,but the manual confused me ,because it says i need to build the libraries from the source to use them. I just misunderstood everything,because i'm not very good in java. I have downloaded the sources and build them into eclipse projects(just for interest)Also i figured out how to bind the libraries to my eclipse proj as jar files,and because i don't need to modify them this is the way to go for me.